# How to import ibm_db module in Jest framework?

Tags: jestjs

In the beforeAll section I'm calling a function which makes use of the ibm_db module, installed and loaded through `const ibmdb = require('ibm_db');`. Launching the tests I'm getting the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find specified module.
    \\?\<path-to-repo>\node_modules\ibm_db\build\Release\odbc_bindings.node

      at Runtime._loadModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:991:29)
      at bindings (node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js:57:31)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install ibm_db according to its instructions? I am guessing the module didn't build properly and you may need to try to rebuild it.

Comment: https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/773